# Derivative of the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I find the derivative of the functions :

$$F(x)= \int_x^5 \sqrt{1+t^2} dt$$ in $x=0,x=3/4$

I know that I must use the FTC but how can I use it in this specific points?

Comment: What does the FTC say? Stating it explicitly will help you.

Comment: That if f is continuos on [a,b] and G a primitive then \int_a^b f(u)du = G(b) -G(a)

Comment: FTC = Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Write it as $F(x) =  - \int_5^x g(t) dt$ and apply the FTC to this.

Comment: @Knight Use the other part of the FTC, that $D_x \int_c^x f(t) \, \mathrm dt = f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of the fundamental theorem of Calculus you want is:

$$D_x \displaystyle \int_c^x f(t) \, \mathrm dt = f(x)$$

where $c$ is constant (simple case).

In your function the upper bound is a constant, not the lower bound, do you know a way to flip the bounds of an integral without changing its values?

Comment: With a minus I can change de integral - D_x int_x^c f(t) t= f(x) ?

Comment: @Knight correct! Note that you can put your math formula in dollar signs to make it look nice like the other posters are doing.

Comment: The for x=0 the derivative is -1 and for x=3/4 the derivative is -5/4 is that correct?

Comment: @Knight correct